# Punctuation before an addendum

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

> - Over the cemetery a cloud always hangs, a thick grey one.
> - Over the cemetery a cloud always hangs; a thick grey one.
> - Over the cemetery a cloud always hangs—a thick grey one.

Which of these is preferable?

Comment: Don't label things "grammar" that are not. Thank you.

Comment: Please keep it friendly. Avoid sarcasm.

Answer (score -1):

Of these choices #3 is best, although a colon would serve here as well (some would say better). A semicolon separates independent clauses, which these are not. A comma isn't generally used to set off a simple descriptive phrase.

Comment: Actually, a comma is required for a nonrestrictive appositive, which is what _a thick grey one_ is. Colon or dash is stylistic preference, but I'd go for the m-dash as well.